# Why onClick function not return the tags, in console all good

Tags: reactjs

After onClick I must render information about other users that I get from server
In console, all info is passed, but not render. Also I try simple, like `${item.name}`, but nothing. That’s why I understand,

I’m doing something wrong, WHAT? thanks))

```
<Consumer>
{value => {
const { users_ } = value;
return (<ButtonContainer
onClick={() => {users_.forEach(item => {
return (
<React.Fragment>
<div className='col-sm-6 d-inline-flex p-4'>
<img src='${item.photo}'className='usersImg' />
<h3>`${item.name}`</h3>
<p className='p2'>`${item.position}`<br />`${item.email}`<br />`${item.phone}`</p>
</div>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
);}}</Consumer>
```

That’s why I wrote, no errors, nothing((

Comment: Your component should display the users based on some state. The button onClick function should just be updating that state, which would cause the component to re-render and then output the users because the state says so (ex. state changes from false to true).

Comment: You want to say that I can’t render in the same component? I should pass value in other?

Comment: I am saying dont try to output more JSX inside the `onClick`. The `onClick` function should just be changing some piece of state. That change in state informs the component to re-render and you can show the new JSX based on that updated state. Research conditional rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: My component render some Users, I need that button just add more users from server. How me do this?

Comment: I have explained already in my comments.